# Call unsecure api from secure application in Angular

Tags: angular, https

Is there anyway to call unsecured (http) API from SSL secured (https) Angular application?

Currently I am getting blocked:mixed-content error.

I tried to add the following meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

It changed all api request from http to https. However, server api does not support https so it fails. We dont have control on server api so unable to fix it from server side.

Is there anyway to call http api from https angular application?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a `proxy.conf.json` then set `secure` to false then call that proxy path?

From the docs:

Create a file proxy.conf.json in your project's src/ folder.

Add the following content to the new proxy file:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

In the CLI configuration file, angular.json, add the proxyConfig option to the serve target:

```
  "architect": {
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "your-application-name:build",
        "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
      },
…
```

To run the development server with this proxy configuration, call ng serve.

[offical docs](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server)

Comment: I will try this, thanks.